# Unhandled exception on generic type<T> in c# because file size not multiple of bytes

Tags: c#, generics, binaryfiles, binary-data, generic-programming

I am `C#` beginner and trying to read a binary file to calculate the `frequency` of the `symbols` inside the `binary file`. (Frequency is the number of time the symbols repeats).

As first step I kept the `data type` of `"symbol"` read as `"int"` and **code worked fine.**
But now I wanted to make this symbol of **`generic type`** (I mean `<T>` type).

The code compiles with out any error in Ubuntu terminal.

But when I execute using `"mono filename.exe BinaryFile.bin"` This binary file is read at `sole argument`. Please see at last that how i got this Binary file **BinaryFile.bin**

The error is : (I know the cause of this error, I have mentioned below but don't know the soultion.)

```
   hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/templatescplus$ mono cbk.exe  toto.bin 

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
  at System.BitConverter.PutBytes (System.Byte* dst, System.Byte[] src, Int32 start_index, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.BitConverter.ToInt64 (System.Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Final.A`1[System.Int64]..ctor (System.String[] args, System.Func`3 converter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Final.MyClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
  at System.BitConverter.PutBytes (System.Byte* dst, System.Byte[] src, Int32 start_index, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.BitConverter.ToInt64 (System.Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Final.A`1[System.Int64]..ctor (System.String[] args, System.Func`3 converter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Final.MyClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/templatescplus$
```

My equivalent of full code to do so is (narrowed code, it do the same you can compile it if you want):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Final 
{
    public class A <T> where T: struct, IComparable <T> , IEquatable <T> 
    {
        public class Node 
        {
            public T symbol;
            public Node next;
            public int freq;
        }

        public Node Front;

        public A(string[] args, Func <byte[], int, T> converter) 
        {    
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (T));
            Front = null;
            using(var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0]))) 
            {   
                while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length) 
                {   
                    byte[] bytes = stream.ReadBytes(size);   
                    T processingValue = converter(bytes, 0);  

                    Node pt, temp;
                    pt = Front;

                    while (pt != null) 
                    {   Console.WriteLine("check1");
                        if (pt.symbol.Equals(processingValue)) 
                        {
                            pt.freq++;
                            break;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0}  frequency is : {1}", pt.symbol, pt.freq);
                        temp = pt;
                        pt = pt.next;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyClass 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            A <long> ObjSym = new A <long> (args, BitConverter.ToInt64);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is created while creating object of type Huffman in `public class MyClass`. Could some one please help me how to get a rid of this problem by giving a solution (any piece of code would be highly appreciated)? Thanks. 
Important: I know why i get this Unhandled exception error. Its just due to this Object declaration :

```
A <long> ObjSym = new A <long> (args, BitConverter.ToInt64);
```

But if i do so there is no error at all.

```
A <short> ObjSym = new A <short> (args, BitConverter.ToInt16);
```

But it gives wrong output (because it **read 2 bytes together but I want read only 1 byte at a time**).
The error disappears, The error was because this file must be the multiple of 16 in case of BitConverter.ToInt16 and multiple of 64 in case of BitConverter.ToInt64.

Where as to get the correct output from this binary file I must have something like :
A  ObjSym = new A  (args, BitConverter.ToInt8);

It is because the size of byte is "8 bits" and I have to read each "8 bits" **But I found no data type in C# which could hold 8 bits for example as I have kept "short" for BitConverter.Toint16 and "long" for Bitconverter.Toint64 and may others. Could some one please tell me it's "8 bit equivalent integer type ?"** would be a big help. Thanks

Comment: You should check if `bytes` really contains `size` bytes. If the stream has reached its end, you may end up with less bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the line:

byte[] bytes = stream.ReadBytes(size);

When the method stream.ReadBytes reads < 8 bytes, then byte[] array has a length < 8 and in the method BitConverter.ToInt64(byte[] value, int startIndex) occurs the error.

Comment: thanks, Yes i got it but when i was using "symbol" as "int" type (without using generics, both "processingValue" and "symbol" in Node class were int) then it was working fine. But what i want to know is how should i change my BitConverter.ToInt64(byte[] value, int startIndex) and other parts of code so that it will work properly ? where else i should make changes ? could you help me please ? Thanks.

Comment: I think i have to find the equivalent of "BitConverter.ToInt8" by doing something like "A < short> ObjSym = new A < short > (args, BitConverter.ToInt8);". Am i right ? (may be not necessarily "short" because it is "2 byte", i have to find it's 1 byte equivalent). Am i right? I really not able to do it yet. Could you please help me in doing that ? Thanks

Comment: There is no BitConverter for byte type because you can read directly a byte value from byte array.
I think you have an issue in your architecture. When your generic class is used, A <long> ObjSym = new A <long> (args, BitConverter.ToInt64), the user must inject right BitConverter. I think it would better if the class encapsulates this functionality. I’d suggest asking the question on [link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)